# Fitting a Gaussian Process model to PCA. Predictions looks very wrong

Tags: python, scikit-learn, model, regression, pca

I'm currently trying to fit a Gaussian Process model to my data and have it predict some days ahead. I have reduced my ~10 features down to just 2 components via PCA in sklearn. So now I have PCA1 and PCA2. This was obtained by performing PCA on the training set (40%).

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(train_data)
PCAs = pca.transform(train_data)
PCA1 = PCAs[:,0]
PCA2 = PCAs[:,1]
```

where `train_data` is the dataframe with ~10 features and 50 rows and `StandardScaler()` applied to it.

```
kernel = RBF()
model = gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, normalize_y=True, n_restarts_optimizer=10)
model.fit(x_days_train, PCA1)
y_pred, y_std = model.predict(x_days, return_std=True)
model.score(x_days_train, PCA1)
```

where `x_days` if the full 50 days, and `x_days_train` is 20 days (0,1,2....). I get a score of 1.0. However, my predicted results looks terrible (as per below). It's like after the training data, it just falls and then stagnates.

[image]

Not entirely sure what went wrong, but a couple guesses:

- Since my data has no target variables, I used PCA on all the features in the dataframe and they are supposed to be x variables? And then I used them as a y variable (by predicting). Maybe this is an incorrect approach?
- Following that, can PCA even be used as y_prediction?
- Am I supposed to apply PCA to not just the training data, but also to the test data (apply `fit_transform`)?
- I seem to be only using PCA1 and not PCA2 (nor a combination of the two). Should I use both? If so, how?

Would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: You are supposed to train the PCA on the train data, but to apply it on both the train and test data. The `GaussianProessRegressor` can take multi-dimensional inputs, so you don't even have to apply a PCA on your input. If you want to do so however, I think `model.fit(x_days_train, PCAs)` may work. If you only want to use one component (for instance, because of your kernel), using `PCA(n_components=1)` is likely to give better results, though there's a high chance you lose the complexity inherent to your data.

Comment: @Knovolt how are you planning to predict a label that doesn't exist?

Comment: @TristanNemoz I tried putting my Pandas dataframe of my features as an input in `.fit()` when using `GaussianProcessRegressor`. But, it will say that I'm missing a y variable. I'm not sure what to put as the y variable since I just want a model that generally learns from the given training set and predict/form a curve of sort for what would be the testing part of the data (and future days past that too if applied on a future set of data).

Comment: @wundermahn When plotting my PCA component, it has a upward trend as the days go by. I'm hoping to get a model to learn from the training set (first 20 days) and predict / show a curve of what the 20+ days would look like.

Comment: This seems like a time series problem. Trying to predict behavior over time. Why are you using regression? What problem are you trying to solve? @knovolt

Comment: @wundermahn Yes that is what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to model the end of life of a machine. I'm hoping that by training the model on this particular dataset, it can also predict future behaviour over time for other similar dataset that I may give it. Is GP not a suitable method for a time series dataset/this problem?

Comment: Correct. `GaussianProcessRegressor`, per the documentation (and it's purpose), `...are a generic supervised learning method designed to solve regression and probabilistic classification problems.` You are looking for a time series model, not a regression model. That likely explains why your approach seems difficult to understand the results are nonsensical. If you can post some of your data, I can provide an answer showing a basic time series approach for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Since my data has no target variables, I used PCA on all the features
> in the dataframe and they are supposed to be x variables? And then I
> used them as a y variable (by predicting). Maybe this is an incorrect
> approach?

You are correct. PCA is meant to transform high dimensional data into much smaller dimensions. Essentially the data is compressed but still contains the same information relative to each element in the data. Sci-kit learns transform function does not accept  y variable. Instead use the fit_transform() function which accepts both variables applying the correct methods to the x variable and ignores the y.

> Following that, can PCA even be used as y_prediction?

PCA is only transforming the data, Gaussian Process Regression (GPR) is making predictions.

> Am I supposed to apply PCA to not just the training data, but also to
> the test data (apply fit_transform)?

Yes.

> I seem to be only using PCA1 and not PCA2 (nor a combination of the
> two). Should I use both? If so, how?

After using the fit_transform() method like this:

```
pca_x, pca_y = pca.fit_transform(train_data)
```

Apply the data like this:

```
kernel = RBF()
model = gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, normalize_y=True, n_restarts_optimizer=10)
model.fit(pca_x, pca_y)
```

Here are the Sci-kit Learn user guides for [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#pca) and [GPR](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#gaussian-process).

Comment: Once I have fitted the model to the 2 PCA components, how should I go about predicting the rest of the data? model.predict(X). What should X be in this case? The pca_x component once I applied pca.fit_transform on the testing dataset?

Comment: @Knovolt You should use the predict method on your x testing data and it will output predicted (y) data that you can compare to your y testing data. This is supervised learning so the fit method is essentially giving you a function that fits your training data and now that you have the function you can use the predict method to find the y variable associated with any x you input.

Comment: Just to confirm, predict method on `x_test` (after PCA is applied to it. i.e. the test set of the principal component... or the test set with the full amount of features before PCA was applied to it). Since I fit my model to `pca_y`, would I compare it to the test set of my `pca_y`. for example, `pca_y_test`.

Comment: Yes, predict with x_test and compare with y_test. Fit with x_train and y_train. PCA will always be done first before training and testing, it is not mandatory though. I would actually recommend trying with and without PCA and observe the differences. You should have 4 variables (x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test). [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) is a method that can split your data into those variables in 1 line of code.